# Width: 100% not filling up screen on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, width, screen, compatibility

I'm currently trying to optimize a Wordpress site for mobile devices, but I'm struggling with getting the footer of the site to cooperate. The site is here:
http://whitehallrow.com/

When loaded on mobile, the width of the body shrinks in accordance with the screen size and wraps all the contained text within it. However, the footer keeps its width, which I understand is because the width is hard-coded to look good on a computer screen. I've made a media query in the CSS that targets devices with screens 500 pixels wide or smaller, in order to get the footer to resize to the width of the body. Here is a snippet of my CSS that I've been tweaking:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
#customfooter{
        width:100%;
}
}
```

For whatever reason, this is not working - it still shows the footer as being much wider than the body. I've tried max-width:100%, width:auto; max-width:auto, and none of them work.

How do I achieve this without hard-coding anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS from

```css
#teakfooter {
    width: 100%;
}
#verybottom {
    width: 100%;
}
```

add a class so this gets higher priority

```css
.page #teakfooter {
    width: 100%;
}
.page #verybottom {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I tried it out using Firebug and it seems to be working well like this.

Edit: After going over a few more things in the comments, I noticed a couple of things causing the footer to not fill out.

```
.site {
    padding: 0 1.71429rem;
}
```

This is causing #customer footer to have padding on both sides.

```
#teakfooter {
    margin-left: -40px;
}
```

This is causing #teakfooter to have whitespace on the right side.

Comment: When I load it on my Blackberry Bold, the footer does shrink, but it becomes too narrow and only takes up about 80% of the width of the body...

Comment: Try updating your CSS with this:
    .page #customfooter {
        height: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

Comment: height:auto; somehow made the #customfooter disappear, and margin:0; keeps the div narrower than the body and centres it.

Comment: I see what you mean about customer footer disappearing with height: auto. The background goes away, but the content is still there. I tried messing around with adding a div to clear all the floats so the height: auto maintains the background image, but it just ended up tiling but didn't fix the width issue, which is sort of the point. There's some padding on .site causing that to happen. And a  margin-left: -40px; on #teakfooter causing it to not fill the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

also in firebug you can check METRICS (in right column you have Computed Styles, Styles, Metrics, etc.). In METRICS you will see that around your body there is a `padding: 24px;`

Solution:

```
body {
  padding: 0; 
}
```